# Firestore Snapshot Listener - Inconsistent fromCache value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Web App Firestore client library and there is this behavior with the fromCache metadata that I dont grasp:

1. When my app launches, the listener is started and it will first pull the data from the cache, with fromCache=true
2. Then it will pull the latest data, GOOD! But most often than not I still see fromCache=true! I have ensured that this is indeed pulled from the server by removing the internet access, then this second step does not occur.

When I write "most often than not" I mean that sometimes I have the expected result fromCache=false, but it seems random. From all the doc I read, for instance at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline, step 2 should always show fromCache=false.

I have tried setting the options { includeMetadataChanges: true } but it does not change anything

EDIT: I am using two test users for this, from the same client machine. The first user uses an instance of the app in Firefox and the other in Chrome (to make sure they wont share any persistence data). So all changes to the data should come from the Cloud.

Comment: Where are the changes to your data made? Are they made on device or in the cloud?

Comment: From the cloud, I have added more info on this